# glPolygonOffset equivalent in Javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-3d

I'm trying to plot two MeshView at exact same location, one rendered with FILL and the other with LINE in order to give it wireframe looks. But unfortunately the wireframe only appears on the backside of the mesh as shown below.

In Java3D I fixed this problem using glPolygonOffset. Is there an equivalent to that in javafx?

[image]

Comment: hi , I did the exact same thing : two shape3d concrete instances , same position , but draw mode fill and wire  and i have what you espected . I can see wireframe in front of filled mesh

Comment: normals are facing inside in your mesh , perhaps